# What is the appropriate auth to access the google admin ListTrustedApps API?

Tags: api, google-apis-explorer

specifically, I'm trying to use the API described at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resolvedAppAccessSettings/ListTrustedApps, but the API explorer uses a demo API key (which results in a 401).  When I try to specify oauth scopes for the directory API (and I've tried them all, because the required scope section of the API description is empty), I get a 403 every time.

For reference, I'm authed as the domain admin, and I can access the directory user API just fine (eg https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list).

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same problem

Comment: sorry, never did figure it out.  The work I was doing it for got deprioritized, so I haven't been digging recently.  I expect to be picking this up again in the next month or so, though.  If you figure it out in the meantime, please let me know!